# Sitecore pipelines initialize processor initializeroutes runtime error

Tags: pipelines

Getting `Sitecore pipelines initialize processor initializeroutes runtime error`:-

**causing runtime error**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Patch:before` instead of patch:after:

```
<pipelines>
  <initialize>
    <processor type="xxx, xx" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
  </initialize>
</pipelines>
```

Comment: I tried using patch:before, but got the same result ... runtime error.

Comment: should i use  Sitecore.Mvc or Sitecore.Kernel ?

Comment: @luckymow8 you need to use Sitecore.Mvc

Answer (score 0):

There can be two possible cases according to my findings.

- Try renaming your config file to `z.yourconfigname.config` or create a `zzz` folder in `App_Config -> Include` folder and keep your patch file in it. Because it can be a reason that your `config` file comes before `Sitecore.Mvc.config` file. That's why the patch is not working.
- If copy configuration text directly from a web page, then there is a chance that an invisible character exists in your `config`. So open this in an editor and remove that character can fix your issue.

Hope the first one will resolve your issue.

Thanks